# std::vector<WCHAR> not freeing memory automatically in C++

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Here is some code I'm having difficulty with:

```
unsigned __stdcall Thread_GetInstallType(void *pComputerName)
{
std::vector<WCHAR> sInstallationType(10240);
INT iVal = Calculate(sInstallationType.data());
return iVal;
}
```

I have found that `std::vector<WCHAR>` memory allocated is not always freed when it goes out of scope, so my program has a leak. If I do a `.clear()` and a `.shrink_to_fit()`, the program does not leak memory. So I may as well use WCHAR/calloc instead of std::vector??? Or is best practice to use std::vector?

Here is the code with the clear/shrink which does not leak memory:

```
unsigned __stdcall Thread_GetInstallType(void *pComputerName)
{
std::vector<WCHAR> sInstallationType(10240);
INT iVal = Calculate(sInstallationType.data());
sInstallationType.clear();
sInstallationType.shrink_to_fit();
return iVal;
}
```

Comment: What does `Calculate` do ? How did you detect the memory leak ? What is `WCHAR` (the one defined on Windows, or something else) ?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that this behavior comes from `std::vector`. My money is on undefined behavior in your code. But we have no way to tell that from an incomplete [mcve]. Also, where do you do `clear()` or `shrink_to_fit()`? Surely not right after allocating?

Comment: Please explain *why* you think the memory associated with the `std::vector` isn't being freed.  How are you testing this?

Comment: The Calculate() function does its calculations, then copies the result into sInstallationLog. `INT Calculate(TCHAR *sInstallTypeOut)` is the function definition. I know it's leaking memory because in testing I spin the thread hundreds of times and the memory of the process is getting eaten up. If I just do a `return` and comment out the `return Calculate(sInstallationType);` line, no memory leaks. And if I call `Calculate`, put a `.clear()` and a `.shrink_to_fit()` before calling return, no leaks.

Comment: You pass a `std::vector<WCHAR>` as a `TCHAR *` ? How does that work ? You really need to provide a mcve like @MaxLanghof asked.

Comment: Yes, Windows APIs (or custom functions) that take `WCHAR *` as an incoming parameter can accept `std::vector<WCHAR>` by using the `.data()`. TCHAR is actually `WCHAR` because the code is compiled in Unicode.

Comment: You state `"Calculate() ... copies the result into sInstallationLog"`.  How?  In the code shown `Calculate` is passed a variable named `sInstallationType` and has no knowledge of `sInstallationLog`.

Comment: Whoops! Typo. Fixed.

Comment: Your code doesn't show that `data()` is called on the vector. Do yourself a favor, and create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and edit it into your question. Until then, there's not much we can help with.

Comment: Please, create a [mcve]. Your current code is sketchy (the pointer `sInstallationType.data()` becomes invalid the moment `Thread_GetInstallType` returns) but any answer would have to guess and assume what `Calculate` does. So as it stands, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: I have searched and ready many forum questions/answers about std::vector actually does leak memory and the only way to free it is with `.clear()` and `.shrink_to_fit()` in C++ 11.0 and higher. I'm using VS 2017, so that's not an issue.

Comment: It doesn't leak memory, you're mistaken. My guess is that you're mistaking increased memory usage in Task Manager for a memory leak

Comment: `std::vector` does not by itself leak memory. Once the `std::vector` **goes out of scope**, it frees the memory it allocated, no need for `.clear()` or `.shrink_to_fit()` - those are only needed when the vector **stays alive** (which it does not in this case - it **dies** as soon as `Thred_GetInstallType` returns). The problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Note that freeing memory in your `c++` code (especially a small allocation) need not release the memory to the OS. Your OS probably requires giving back a block of several KB at a time. If the entire block is not empty your CRT can't give it back. Also giving it back is an expensive operation so it likely will not try to release back to the OS for every delete.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t show the code of `Calculate` (nor how your function is called). It’s entirely possible that `Calculate`, or your calling code, contains undefined behaviour, at which point *all bets are off*, and this might, via some crazy indirect effect, cause memory to be leaked from `Thread_GetInstallType`.

But this is pretty far-fetched. The code, as shown, does not leak memory. The automatically-run destructor will free it.